# Is the language accepted by a DFA with a fixed word on the stack after consuming it a deterministic context free language?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free

Let $\cal M$ be a deterministic stack automaton
${\cal M } = (Q, \Sigma, \Gamma, \delta, q_0, F, Z_0 )$.
Let $\gamma \in \Gamma^* $ a word on the stack alphabet.
Is it true that the language
$$L = \{ w \in \Sigma^*  \mid (q_0,w,Z_0) \vdash^* (q,\epsilon, \gamma),\  q \in F \}$$
is a deterministic context free language?
Is this family different from the family of deterministic context free languages? If so, how is this family of languages called in the literature? I was particullary interested in the case of $\gamma = Z_0$.

*Commentary*: This question was migrated from TCS stack exchange.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I have already deleted the question from TCS stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $L$ is a deterministic context-free language.

I will describe how to build a deterministic pushdown automaton $\mathcal{M}'$ to recognize $L$.  The stack alphabet of $\mathcal{M}'$ is $\Gamma' = \Gamma \times \{0,1,\dots,|\gamma|,\bot\}$.  When the stack of $\mathcal{M}$ contains the word $\beta=(\beta_1,\beta_2,\dots,\beta_k)$, the stack of $\mathcal{M}'$ contains the word

$$\beta'=((\beta_1,m_1),(\beta_1,m_2),\dots,(\beta_k,m_k)),$$

where $m_i=i$ if $i \le |\gamma|$ and $(\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_i)=(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_i)$, or $m_i=\bot$ otherwise.  Also, the states $Q'$ of $\mathcal{M}'$ are given by $Q'=Q \times \{0,1\}$.  When $\mathcal{M}$ is in state $q$, $\mathcal{M}'$ is in state $(q,1)$ if the top of $\mathcal{M}'s$ stack is of the form $(\cdot,|\gamma|)$, or in state $(q,0)$ otherwise.  The accepting states of $\mathcal{M'}$ are $F'=\{(q,1) \mid q \in F\}$.  You should be able to figure out how to adjust the transitions to ensure that $\mathcal{M}'$ behaves as described.

Then $\mathcal{M}'$ accepts exactly $L$, and is deterministic.  I'll let you fill in the details of the proof.

You can generalize this to allow any $\gamma$ such that $\gamma \in R$, where $R$ is a regular language.  (We modify the proof above by replacing $\{0,1,\dots,|\gamma|,\bot\}$ with the states of a DFA recognizing $R$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast and detailed answer. I think I have a construction such that we need to add $|\gamma|$ states and modify the transition function accordingly.
Also, is it true that this family of languages is strictly contained in the family of deterministic context-free languages? I thought of a counterexample, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @lenareole, I think yes, it is a deterministic context-free - if you work through the construction I believe all of the transition function of $\mathcal{M}'$ will remain deterministic.  But please check my reasoning carefully, I might well have made some mistake.  If you have a construction that avoids the need to blow up the stack alphabet, that's very nifty!

Comment: The final remark (suggesting acceptance using a regular string on the stack) is very elegant. This reminds us that the set of (all) stacks that occur during a PDA computation is itself regular.

Comment: Alternatively (I think) the bottom $|\gamma|$ symbols of the pushdown can be kept in the finite state memory of the machine. (Moving the explosion from stack symbols to states.)

Comment: @D. W. My nifty construction turned out to be erroneous as I thought it was but couldn't understand why. I think I was able to construct a deterministic pusdown automata that accepts the language of words accepted with $\gamma$ as a prefix, which is less difficult to do.